# Android Studio always excludes build/source folder

Tags: android, annotations, gradle, android-studio

I'm using an annotation processor to generate code in android studio and ran into t
he problem that with every build android studio re-adds (i manually delete it every now and then) the following line to the module's .iml file:

```
<excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source" />
```

Does anyone know a setting or a way to prevent this?
I'm maybe thinking of a gradle task to delete this line from the file but i've never done anything like this. Can someone point me to the right direction?

I'm using the latest android studio version in beta update channel, which is 0.8.2
Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Just to clarify: everything builds fine, but android studio shows a lot of errors in the editor and i can't use functions like "find usages" and "jump to definition" properly.

Comment: Why do you want that to be included? None of your annotations will be in there, as that's all code generated by the build process, AFAICT.

Comment: My generated code is in build/source/apt/debug, is including the folder the wrong way to fix this, maybe i should try to move my generated sources to a different folder?

Comment: "maybe i should try to move my generated sources to a different folder?" -- ah, I see where you're going. You might peek at other open source compile-time annotation processing packages (Butterknife?) and see how they handle it.

Comment: use build/generated/source instead?

Comment: I found that an update of android-apt moves the sources to a different folder and answered my own question. Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for guiding me in the right direction, the answer is to use a different source folder or in my case to update android-apt to a version >= 1.3 in build.gradle, like this:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.3+'
```

I still had 1.2.+, see this link to the author's git for more details:
https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/issue/13/compatibility-with-011-android-plugin